# Glass Mapper - Item not null when language version not present

Tags: glass-mapper, multilingual, language-fallback

I'm using Glass 5.4.18 with Sitecore 9.0.2. I have a base template for my site that has language fallback turned on by default, but for a few items the client wants to disable language fallback so the item does not appear in certain languages.

I've gone into the individual item in a navigation tree and unchecked Enable Language Fallback, and I've tried this both with and without Enforce Version Presence checked on. But when I retrieve the item in my controller as follows:

```
IGlassBase testGlass = _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<IGlassBase>(new Guid("{5D70191B-546B-4902-B764-175F2C4FE6DB}"));
```

The "testGlass" variable is not null like I'd expect it to be. I get the item details back, but if I check the actual item (either through a Glass property marked with the `SitecoreItem` attribute, or using the Sitecore API directly) I see the `Versions.Count` is 0 as I'd expect.

A lot of the prior answers on this topic appear to be from Glass 4 or when language fallback was first introduced, and mention using a VersionCountDisabler. I didn't think any extra wiring was necessary at this stage, but my direct query and looping past them item in a SitecoreChildren iteration yield the item to display in my navigation tree incorrectly.

I feel like I'm missing a setting, but I can't find what it might be, if there's a configuration or script I need to add in. I could do a `.Where` and look for `Versions.Count > 0` but that seems excessive.

Comment: To confirm, when you say you "checked Enforce Version Presence" on/off.. did you go through all steps mentioned here? https://ctor.io/enforce-language-version-presence-for-items-in-sitecore-8-1/

Comment: @jrap You win the kewpie doll...to collect your prize, please put this in as an answer. I'm so used to adding the enableLanguageFallback site setting that I missed the needed one for enforceVersionPresence. Thanks much!

Comment: Hah, thanks, will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a glass mapper issue, but instead a miss on the full Enforce Language Presence implementation.

Per [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/enforce-version-presence.html):

### 1) Enable the enforceVersionPresence attribute

This attribute is applicable to a `<site>` definition element. [Patch it in appropriately](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configuration-patch-file-examples.html).

```
<site name="mysite">
  <patch:attribute name="enforceVersionPresence">true</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

*Note: Do not patch this into the `shell` site definition.*

### 2) Enforce version presence on your template

> To enable enforce version presence on an item or a data template:
>
> In the Content Editor, navigate to the relevant item or template, in
> the **Advanced** section, select **Enforce Version Presence**.
>
> **Note:**
>
> You can also enable this on a base template to allow data
> templates to inherit the setting from there.

Comment: The link I referenced in my comment specified to include this attribute on the "shell" site, but Sitecore documentation specifically says to NOT do this.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out by doing, I noticed by setting it up on "shell" you only see the languages in the dropdown you have content for. Thank you very much for the help!