# Component addedon SharedLayout without a version is displayed

Tags: glass-mapper

Following the below steps, we see an issue in Sitecore v9.3.0 + Glass V5.6.160, compared to Sitecore v9.0.1 + Glass v4.5.0.4:

1. Create a datasource item, version ONLY in EN culture. the fields has field level fallback enabled.
2. For a page in EN culture, add component via SharedLayout and associate with datasource item above.
3. For the selected page in #2, add version in a different language (NOT English culture).
4. View the page on CMS for the language selected in #3 (NOT English culture), you will notice "the component shows on the CMS page, even though a version does not exist for the component."

In sitecore v9.0.1 + GlassV4, the component is shown in Experience Editor and NOT shown on CMS site.

In Sitecore v9.3.0 + GlassV5, the component is shown in Experience Editor and ALSO shown on CMS site.

- Note: we have the [VersionCountDisabler](http://glass.lu/mapper/documentation/Upgrade-ToV5) customization as below `dependencyResolver.ObjectConstructionFactory.Remove<ItemVersionCountByRevisionTask>();`
- Also, if I try to use the below customization, the component is NOT shown on both CMS page & Experience Editor, which is not correct. [reference here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/glassmapper-5-sitecorechildren-listing-items-even-if-the-version-count-is-0#answer-19770)
  `dependencyResolver.ObjectConstructionFactory.Replace<ItemVersionCountByRevisionTask, ItemVersionCountTask>(() => new ItemVersionCountTask());`

EXPECTED: if a Language version does not exist, the component on SharedLayout shall NOT show on the CMS page. But shall show in the experience editor allowing content Authors to edit/create.

I have also tried ([reference](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/glass-mapper-item-not-null-when-language-version-not-present#answer-18734)) setting the enforceVersionPresence=true on the site, and checking the Enforce Version on Datasource Item template. It does not produce the EXPECTED result.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I have enabled the following as referenced [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/glass-mapper-item-not-null-when-language-version-not-present#answer-18734)

1. Enable the enforceVersionPresence attribute on site definition.
2. Enforce version presence on your template

Note: you may reset fields on you templates, when using a baseComponent template.